# ActionCable wouldn't broadcast notification from sidekiq job, but works fine from console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, actioncable

I'm trying to get up to speed on ActionCable and am having some issues getting messages to broadcast. My goal is straightforward: I have a sidekiq job running, and at the end of the job, I want to notify the front-end that the job is complete. I have reduced it down the the bare bone and it's still not working.

If I submit the broadcast command in console, everything works fine (i.e., message shows up in console), but not when it's called inside the sidekiq job. When I call `NotificationBroadcastWorker.perform_async(user_id)`, the broadcast command returns nil.
I have also made sure to update `cable.yml` to use redis in development per comments on this other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38908012/sidekiq-perform-later-not-working-with-action-cable). Maybe there's some other weird configuration issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Below are my code snippets:

notification_broadcast_worker.rb

```
class NotificationBroadcastWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast "notification_channel.#{user_id}", { action: "new_notification", message: "record was successfully updated" }
  end
end
```

notification_channel.rb

```
class NotificationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    # stream_from "some_channel"
    stream_from "notification_channel.#{current_user.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

notification_channel.js

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("NotificationChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
    console.log("connected to notication channel")
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```

application_cable/connection.rb

```
module ApplicationCable
  class Connection < ActionCable::Connection::Base
    identified_by :current_user

    def connect
      self.current_user = find_verified_user
    end

    private

    def find_verified_user
      if verified_user = env['warden'].user
        verified_user
      else
        reject_unauthorized_connection
      end
    end
  end
end
```

cable.yml

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379/1

test:
  adapter: test

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: <%= ENV.fetch("REDIS_URL") { "redis://localhost:6379/1" } %>
  channel_prefix: oakheart_production
```

Comment: could you show how you call `NotificationBroadcastWorker.perform_async(user_id)` ( on controller ) ? although it's `async` but you should aware that the `cable connection establish` also take time, so maybe your worker run before the `cable connection` establish successful.

Comment: to test the 2, I tried invoking both "NotificationBroadcastWorker.perform_async(user_id)" and "ActionCable.server.broadcast directly from the console. the former returned nil while the latter returned 1. i tried adding a sleep(1) within the sidekiq job as well. result is the same

Comment: try `NotificationBroadcastWorker.perform_in(1.minute, user_id)` and make sure that you see the connection logs appear on rails console before the log on sidekiq console.

Comment: Did you make any progress with this in the end? I'm having the same problem.